# Printing stack variables during stack unwinding

Tags: windows, visual-c++, exception

Is it possible in some way to access local variables (and method arguments) during stack unwinding after an exception is thrown? It is quite trivial to get methods names using `StackWalk64` but I wonder if I can get to variables so I can better understand the problem.

Comment: You can create a full dump. That won't help you in printing stuff to some log, but when you open the dump in VS or WinDbg, you'll see local variables (as well as everything allocated on the heap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you run the process under a debugger (including your own home-made debugger), it is not possible to get local variables AFTER exception is thrown and you reach the exception handler. The call stack is already unwinded.

You may however get the call stack (not in all circumstances), using SEH instead of C++ exception handling.